# Least regularity of boundary to have Lipschitz or bounded mean curvature?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, curvature, regularity-theory-of-pdes

For domains of class $C^{1,1}$, I know that the mean curvature of its boundary belongs to $L^{\infty}(\partial \Omega)$. Is $C^{1,1}$ regularity the least regularity needed for the mean curvature to be in $L^{\infty}(\partial \Omega)$? How about the conditions on the boundary of a domain to have bounded mean curvatures? Which references discusses this kind of topic?